# spring boot error 404 while starting jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I’m trying to run a spring boot application. I downloaded a code from a tutorial so I know the code works. When I run my jar file, it looks like the applications I running on port 8080 but still I get 404 for any URL, I never got the spring white label page. I checked that I don’t have anything else running on port 8080, and the server I up and running.

I have no clue why my applications are not responding.

[running the jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGeF6.png)

[error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Ncp.png)

```
package com.virtualpairprogrammers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Created by masn on 2017-04-01.
*/

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello";
    }
}


enter code here
```

package com.virtualpairprogrammers;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FleetmanApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(FleetmanApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.virtualpairprogrammers</groupId>
<artifactId>fleetman</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>fleetman</name>
<description>VPP´s Fleet Management Application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Well at least I should get the whitelabel page? And yes I tried adding controllers....

Comment: sorry. check now, didnt do any setting, and follow a tutorial and it works in the video 100% same instructions.

Comment: Well In the vidoe he clearly states that defaul is anyt request type and it works for him without any method stated.

Comment: Added your suggetsion still the same problem

Comment: http://localhost:8080/hello

Comment: looks like the springboot autoconfig is not doing its job......

Comment: Your request mappings doesn't seem to be registered with container so not recognized. Can you share your main application class and pom/gradle file?

Comment: Just use what is in here, and you are set to go, you lack the auto configuration, hence those request mappings are not registered. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-code

Comment: Everything seems fine than there must be a problem with the jar package.  You can either try re building it with `mvn clean install` or can you try running this application from an IDE like Intellij or Eclipse STS?

Comment: already tried that

Comment: Then only thing I can do to help is to try running the app from source on my machine. Can you provide me a link so I can check it out?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-wGGHkmich-ek5kNEJXWUJkbVk

Comment: you can add a controller and see if it works for you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try like this and it will work:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Here's the screenshot I've taken from my computer:
[image: Working Controller]

Comment: This is humiliating but doesnt work for me.....So it must be computer specific issue

Comment: Apparently everything I tried was correct, I guess I will just reformat my computer and try again...

Comment: Mattias apparently everything you tried wasn't correct because it would run. You have configured something wrong.... btw it works for me as well...

Comment: did you try adding `path="/hello"` and `method=RequestMethod.GET` right?

Comment: of course , and also I have tried downloading different sample springboot projects which i know works. Even tried it on my other computer now and works fine....so clearly its computer specific.....

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found the issue.....I tried different versions from http://start.spring.io/  and it seems my mac can only handle spring version 1.3.8 , anything else wont run.

Comment: I'm glad you could resolve the issue with your computer.

Comment: People like you deserve some cred, your solution helped me to confirm i was doing it right, so thats why I cam to conclusion that it must be a version issue....

Comment: In your case, probably a version issue otherwise as you've said its a simple project from a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command java -jar YourAppName.jar you must be located inside the root folder (*fleetman*) and **NOT INSIDE** the *target* folder where the .jar is located.
This is a common mistake so run the command inside the fleetman folder.

You might want to update the pom.xml with this

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```